# Sorting an array in PHP vs fetching data from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I am using the following php method to find the top 10 occuring elements in an array and then returning a new array with those 10 elements along with how many times they appear. This is fine for rather small arrays. But I get my data from a database and the arrays can easily be over 100000 in size. This causes this method to be extremely slow. The code is as follows:

```php
function getTopTenSelects($array) {
    $result = [];
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
        $count = countArray($array);
        $mostOccuring = (key($count));
        $arrayReturn[$x] = $mostOccuring;
        array_push($result, [$mostOccuring,$count[$mostOccuring]]);
        foreach ($array as $temp) {
            if (($key = array_search($mostOccuring, $array)) !== false) {
                // Cuts the key from the array foreach time it appears so we can find the next most occuring value
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Now. I get my array through the following SQL query. `$hashtag` is a variable that contains a piece of string.

```sql
SELECT tag_names
FROM soc_stat
JOIN tags on soc_stat.insta_id = tags.insta_id
WHERE main_tag = $hashtag
```

Is there an efficient way of doing it in php, or is there a way to get what I need through an SQL query?

Comment: What table do `tag_names` and `main_tag` reside in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you should retrieve only the data from the database that is really needed in order to have small data exchange. In your case the top 10 tag names:

```sql
SELECT tag_names, count(*)
FROM soc_stat
JOIN tags on soc_stat.insta_id = tags.insta_id
WHERE main_tag = $hashtag
group by tag_names
order by count(*) desc limit 10;
```

Comment: Oh god thank you so much. I'm starting to like SQL more and more. Unfortunately I find more and more code I've written that is completely useless. At least I am learning from my mistakes :)